# Angular one way binding is passing the arguments as strings

Tags: angularjs

For some reason all of the directive scope variables are being sent as strings. For example sportid will be the string 'activePlayer.sportID' instead of the value of activeplayer.SportID in the below example.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a possible issue with something else in the code.

View:

```
<tbody profilestats sportid="{{activePlayer.sportID}}" season={{activePlayer.season}}" posid="{{activePlayer.positionID}}" playerid={{activePlayer.id}}" statstype="bo"></tbody>
```

In the profile stats Directive:

```
    directive.scope = {
    leagueid: '@',
    playerid: '@',
    sportid: '@',
    season: '@',
    posid: '@',
    statstype: '@'
};
```

**Edit** I am starting to suspect (even more so) that something else earlier in the code is causing this to break. The suggestions that have already been given I have actually already tried. If I am able to find anything I will post what the issue was.

Comment: If you are using `@` inside a directive for binding anyways it is going to be converted into a string..so you have to convert them to use `=` which will persist the type of data by passing the value to directive isolated scope

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the `@` binding.

Replace `@` by `=` and you will have the correct data inside your directive.

```
leagueId: '=',
playerId: '=',
sportId: '=',
season: '=',
posId: '=',
statsType: '='
```

And in your html:

```
<tbody profilestats sport-id="activePlayer.sportID" season="activePlayer.season" pos-id="activePlayer.positionId" player-id="activePlayer.id" stats-type="bo"></tbody>
```

Comment: When I do that I get        :               

Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression       [{{activePlayer.id}}] starting at [{activePlayer.id}}].

Comment: Also, pass in `league-id` from your html, as you are using it inside your directive!

Comment: This is half correct, but you need to remove the {{}} from the markup

Comment: Applying all of the above changes (without removing the {{}}'s). I get this error again : `[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{league.leagueID}}] starting at [{league.leagueID}}]`.

 If I remove the {{}}'s I get strings as the attributes again

Comment: @user975911 Right, I pointed out that you needed to remove the {{}} for that reason :)

Comment: edited my comment to include what happens if I remove the {{}}'s

Comment: also @AvijitGupta your original answer is missing quotes around some of the scope parameters.

Comment: Fixed missing quotes

Comment: @user975911 If it's still not working I think you'll need to create an example